# Breaking out of For Loop and If Statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

### My list:

```py
listOfMovies=[the Slow and Confused 9, Somebody, Gorilla vs. King, The Blundering 3: Boss Made Me Do It]
```

***I am trying to take an input and if there is a match to the list, the function will print out the object.***

***If there is no match, the function will print out and ask if I would like to search again or return to the mainmenu.***

```
No results found
1. Search again
2. Return to Main Menu
```

**Currently I am able to print the matches however, I also print out the no results as well.**

**If there are no matches with the input, I want `No results` to be printed.**

***I would like to print out the matches and skip printing the no results found.***

### My code is:

```
def DisplayMovie( movie, i  ):
     print ( "Movie Name: " + str(movie[i].getName()) + ",", "Category:" , movie[i].getCategory())
     return


def SearchBasedOnName(searchString, listOfMovies):
     for i in range ( len(listOfMovies) ):    
          if (searchString.lower()  in  listOfMovies[i].getName().lower()):
                            DisplayMovie( listOfMovies, i)
               
     print("\nNo results found")
     print("1. Search again")
     print("2. Return to Main Menu")
     option3input = input("")
     if option3input == "1":
             searchString = input("\nPlease enter your search input: \n")
     elif option3input == "2":
             printMenu()

searchString = input("\nPlease enter your search input:")
SearchBasedOnName(searchString, listOfMovies)
```

### The output I get:

```py
Please enter your search input: king

Movie Name: Gorilla vs. King

No results found
1. Search again
2. Return to Main Menu
```

Comment: Try to add ```return``` after ```DisplayMovie( listOfMovies, i)```?

Answer (score 0):

The 'in' keyword will be your saviour. Given a list of strings and some comparison criterion then, for example:-

```
mylist = ['abc', 'def']

if 'xyz' in mylist:
  print('Found')
else:
  print('Not found')
```

You should be able to adapt this to your use-case

Answer (score 0):

Put `return` under the `DisplayMovie` in the `if` scope so that you get out of the function right after it did something expected.

```
def SearchBasedOnName(searchString, listOfMovies):
     for i in range ( len(listOfMovies) ):    
          if (searchString.lower()  in  listOfMovies[i].getName().lower()):
              DisplayMovie( listOfMovies, i)
              return
```